# textview is smaller then i want to fill area

Tags: android

In the generation of xml code problem occurred. If I put horizontalScrollView save at the problem, if there is too much text, but when it is not enough to want the entire row is filled.
1. picture txtview must be much smaller than the other.
2. picture is what I want but the gray border is transparent. I don't want to see borders between this three textbox.

http://prntscr.com/4aw45n

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/txtMemory"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" 
           android:layout_weight="10"           
           android:background="@drawable/stackview1"
           android:textColor="@color/darkgreen"
           android:gravity="left"           
           android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
           android:layout_marginLeft = "5sp"/>

        <HorizontalScrollView
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/scrollView"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
           android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
           android:gravity="right">

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtStack"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"           
                android:background="@drawable/stackview1" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If I use horizontalscrollview it surface of textview is compressed.. But I whatever I want it wasn't smaller than weight of screen but it must be all at one line

Comment: Can you please provide a better explanation of the problem?

Comment: if i use horizontalscrollview it surface of textview is compresd ..But i wathever i want it wasnt smaller than weight of screen but it must be all at one line

Answer (score 0):

And answer on the my qustion was:
HorizontalScrollView: fillViewport="true"